# How to decode jpg image from memory?

Tags: python, opencv, numpy, binary, jpeg

I can read a jpg image from disk via PIL, Python OpenCV, etc. into a numpy array via some built-in functions such as (in the case of OpenCV) `arr= cv2.imread(filename)`.

But how do I decode a jpg in binary format directly from memory?

Use case: I want to put a jpg image into a database in binary format and then read it from the db into memory and decode it to a numpy array.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Assuming that you are storing the image data in your db as a `string`, you first need to construct a `numpy` array from that string that can later be converted to an image using [`cv2.imdecode`](http://docs.opencv.org/3.0-beta/modules/imgcodecs/doc/reading_and_writing_images.html#imdecode). For example:

```
img = cv2.imdecode(np.fromstring(img_data, dtype=np.uint8), cv2.IMREAD_UNCHANGED)
```

Answer (score 2):

for Python3 use this way:

```
from scipy import misc
import io

f = open('file.png', 'rb')
fs = f.read()
likefile = io.BytesIO(fs)
face1 = misc.imread(likefile)
```

Python2 has `StringIO`.

Comment: What on earth is `misc`? :)

Comment: good point, jtlz2. I used scipy.misc. I've got it with Anaconda3. Now it's going to be deprecated but the documentation proposes imageio.imread. https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.misc.imread.html

Answer (score -1):

Fetching Images from Url to Jpg

```
    import requests
    from io import BytesIO

    response = requests.get("https://optse.ztat.net/teaser/ES/CW15_ES_bermuda_men.jpg")
    my_img_In_byts = BytesIO(response.content).read()


    path="C:/Users/XX/Desktop/TryingPython/downloadedPic.jpg"

    my_fprinter = open(path, mode='wb')
    print( my_fprinter .write(my_img_In_byts))
    my_fprinter.close()
    print("Done")
```