# How to convert image which type is bytes to numpy.ndarray?

Tags: python-3.x, numpy, scipy

I'm trying to optimize my code.

First, I get an image, which type is bytes

Then I have to write that image to file system.

```
with open('test2.jpg', 'wb') as f:
    f.write(content)
```

Finally I read this image with

```
from scipy import misc
misc.imread('test2.jpg')
```

which convert image to np.array.

I want to skip part where I write image to file system, and get np.array.

**P.S.**: I tried to use np.frombuffer(). It doesn't work for me, cause two np.arrays are not the same.
[Convert str to numpy.ndarray](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47977474/convert-str-to-numpy-ndarray)

For test you can try yourself:

```
file = open('test1.jpg', 'rb')
content = file.read()
```

Comment: can you provide the code that creates `content`?

Comment: content is image which type is bytes. I get it from API request.

Comment: What do you see when you do `print(content)`?

Comment: Something like that \xac\x03\x86_\x8a\x04>\x83\xfe\xa2\xf2T\x0e\xb59\x14p\xc5A\xe7<\xd4\x12\x08\xe0t\xa90J\x14\xfa\x89\xcf\xf4\x

Comment: which API? To get a meanigful answer include a piece of working code that others can try.

Comment: the struct library might be waht you are looking for https://docs.python.org/2/library/struct.html

Comment: file = open('test1.jpg', 'rb')
content = file.read()

Comment: You can try this one

Comment: Take a look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44324944/how-to-decode-jpg-image-from-memory

Answer (score 3, accepted):

My first answer in rap...

> Wrap that puppy in a BytesIO
>
> And away you go

So, to generate some synthetic data similar to what you get from the API:

```
file = open('image.jpg','rb')
content = file.read()
```

That looks like this which has all the hallmarks of a JPEG:

```
content = b'\xff\xd8\xff\xe0\x00\x10JFIF...
```

Now for the solution:

```
from io import BytesIO
from scipy import misc

numpyArray = misc.imread(BytesIO(content))
```

Comment: why not just open the originl file with `misc.imread()` in the first place?

Comment: @DrBwts OP doesn't have the file, he gets its content from some web API - I think.